# Redirect preventing setting a cookie?

Tags: javascript, cookies, try-catch

Upon successful form completion, I would like to A) set a cookie (my code) and then B) redirect the visitor to the thank you page (again, using this `try`...`catch` code provided).

The cookie is successfully set in the absence of the redirect, but when it is present no cookie gets set.

Here is the full script:

```
<script>
  function ml_webform_success_1039364() {
      var webinar_time_cookie = 'webinar_time = ' + countDownDateTimeMilliseconds + '; expires = Fri, 15 Mar 2019 12:00:00 UTC; path=/';
      document.cookie = webinar_time_cookie;
      
      setTimeout(function () {
       window.location.replace("https://domain.tld/webinar-thank-you-page/");
    }, 2000);

    }
</script>
```

Comment: The code does run on `mysite.tld`?

Comment: to clarify: is the issue the try/catch itself or is it the redirect? e.g. if you have a `window.location.href` but not wrapped in a try/catch, is the cookie set then?

Comment: Good question; it still doesn't work. I will update my question.

Comment: Turns out it was that the cookie was only on the page it was set; I lacked the path=/ (didn't know about that one!). I will update my question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened because I didn't add `path=/` to my cookie to ensure that the cookie persisted on all page on my website... it wasn't the redirect that was the problem.

```
<script>
  function ml_webform_success_1039364() {
      var webinar_time_cookie = 'webinar_time = ' + countDownDateTimeMilliseconds + '; expires = Fri, 15 Mar 2019 12:00:00 UTC; path=/';
      document.cookie = webinar_time_cookie;
      window.location.href = "https://domain.tld/webinar-thank-you-page/";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This answer is not unique, but as an answer to this specific question it might be worth keeping here.

Comment: Don’t forget to put the domain attribute. Some browsers have started to reject the cookie if this attribute is not present. Take a look at https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265#page-20